# A problem about Argand diagrams

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question

> When plotting an Argand diagram, do I simply plot the points or do I need to draw arrows from the origin to the points?

Motivation: I self studied for my FP1 exams, which will be held today and just realised that I forgot all about this ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: As far as I remember, one  draws arrows, as there's an identification of a comples number with a vector of the pplane.

Comment: I don't think it matters

Comment: The arrows are not necessary, but are sometimes helpful if there are not many points.

Comment: Most I have encountered are 4 @DougM so I have decided to stick to arrows to be on the safe side. However, I was wondering if there was any formal rule to it.

Comment: You may have something like $\{z| \left|\frac {z-1}{z}\right| = 1\}$ the answer is an infinite set.  Connecting all of the points with lines to the origin would be silly.

Comment: Nah, that isn't even in the FP3 syllabus.